# Displaying a given state both as a modal and a normal view in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I am new to AngularJs and I am trying to implement this unique scenario and facing a design challenge.

I have created a menu nav bar in my app with the help of UI router.
Lets say there are 3 states in my application as represented.

[image]

**The challenge is that I want to display state C as a modal or as a normal view depending upon how it is being navigated to.**
If state C is navigated from the menu, I want to display it as a modal.
If state C is navigated from a specific point in the app, it has to be displayed as a normal view with some additional elements.

I am trying to use just a single template and a controller for both modal and the regular view.
I am using $modal service provided by angular ui bootstrap.
**I would like to add that state C has a UI grid which gets its data populated from a rest service.**

I have tried things like using non url params in state, or  using resolve to pass param to modal and using a separate controller for modal but do not know if it is the right approach without causing code redundancy.

I would appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.
I would love to post the code, but at this point I see it more as a design problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just create a html partial - which is your template, and reference it from both ui-router as **templatePath** and from the $modal as described here http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service.

I think however that the right approach is to create a custom directive - representing the content of tab3 or the modal. Directives are angular's way of reusing and encapsulating code. Once you have that directive - that is, let's say it is called  then referencing it from ng-view is simple. The template (no need for templatePath) just becoms:  and also the same when referenced from $modal.

Hope that helps.